# EmberJS: global class functions depend on a session variable, using Ember-Simple-Auth. Best Practice?

Tags: security, ember.js, user-profile, ember-simple-auth

I had a question regarding best practice when it comes to building a global utility class in EmberJS when the class will exhibit user-specific behavior.

#### The following conditions are all true:

1. The class's methods could be accessed from anywhere in the entire application.
2. The application performs JSON based authentication using Ember-Simple-Auth.
3. The authentication confirmation payload comes with some information about the user.
4. The information received in the token payload will determine the behavior of the utility class's function.

#### My Questions

1. **Is a Util the best option?** 
   Should I be using services and somehow "initialize" this service on a confirmed authentication? My end goal is to use this class from almost  every route/template/component in my application.
2. **How chill are authentication payloads?** Is it OK to send crumbs of user specific information information in the authentication payload in addition to any tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best choice is using services.

They are :

- singleton
- could be injected to any object extended from `Ember.Object`

> Is a Util the best option?

No. Services is best option. You can initialize it after successful authentication hook of ESA. And it could be injected everywhere

> How chill are authentication payloads?

You can send anything. Your `authenticator` is responsible to process it. The payload is saved in `data.authenticated` object in ESA session service